# Undefined symbol after linking C driver dynamically

Tags: c, mongodb, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

I am using the following *make* file to build an application that links against *libbson* and *libmongoc*:

```
CURRENT_DIR=$(shell pwd)

INC=-I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0
INC+=-I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0/bson
INC+=-I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0/mongoc
INC+=-I$(CURRENT_DIR)/thpool
INC+=-I$(CURRENT_DIR)/cJSON

LIBS=/usr/local/lib/

all     :       request.o db_manager.o main.o
    +$(MAKE) -C cJSON all
    +$(MAKE) -C thpool all
    mkdir build
    mv cJSON/*.o build/
    mv thpool/*.o build/
    mv request.o build/
    mv db_manager.o build/
    mv main.o build/
    cp -R libs build/ #make copy of local static libs
    cd build && \
    cc $(INC) -w -pthread main.o request.o db_manager.o cJSON.o cJSON_Utils.o \
    thpool.o $(LIBS)libbson-1.0.so $(LIBS)libmongoc-1.0.so \
    -o ghost-chat

request.o       :       request.c
    cc -w $(INC) -c request.c

db_manager.o    :       db_manager.c
    cc -w $(INC) -c db_manager.c

main.o  :       main.c
    cc -w $(INC) -c main.c

clean   :
    rm -rf build
```

The application builds correctly, but during execution, when I make a call to a *libmongoc* function, it returns the following error:

```
./build/ghost-chat: symbol lookup error: ./build/ghost-chat: undefined symbol: mongoc_collection_insert_one
```

Am I correctly linking the *libmongoc-1.0.so* library? I have built the *libmongoc* driver from the latest tarball - hence the installation directory of /usr/local/*. I have tested the application successfully - using Xcode on macOS, using it's own build system, but I have written this *make* file to allow building on our *Nix server.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have built the libmongoc driver from the latest tarball - hence the installation directory of /usr/local/*

Is there *also* `libmongoc-1.0.so` in a standard system directory (`/usr/lib`, or whatever the default is for your system) ?

If so, you are probably loading the *wrong* `libmongoc-1.0.so` at runtime (and that system version lacks the `mongoc_collection_insert_one` symbol).

Running `ldd ./build/ghost-chat` should show which `libmongoc` the runtime loader finds, and running `nm -D libmongoc-1.0.so | grep mongoc_collection_insert_one` on that version should confirm that the symbol is not defined.

What you want to do is link your binary with `-Wl,-rpath=$(LIBS)`, so that `/usr/local/lib` is searched before `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "libmongoc" version 1.0, so you should use the same examples for this version. Please, get the related example form this like:

http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.0.0/index.html!

for example to insert a record use this:

```
#include <bson.h>
#include <mongoc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int   argc,
      char *argv[])
{
    mongoc_client_t *client;
    mongoc_collection_t *collection;
    mongoc_cursor_t *cursor;
    bson_error_t error;
    bson_oid_t oid;
    bson_t *doc;

    mongoc_init ();

    client = mongoc_client_new ("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
    collection = mongoc_client_get_collection (client, "test", "test");

    doc = bson_new ();
    bson_oid_init (&oid, NULL);
    BSON_APPEND_OID (doc, "_id", &oid);
    BSON_APPEND_UTF8 (doc, "hello", "world");

    if (!mongoc_collection_insert (collection, MONGOC_INSERT_NONE, doc, NULL, &error)) {
        printf ("%s\n", error.message);
    }

    bson_destroy (doc);
    mongoc_collection_destroy (collection);
    mongoc_client_destroy (client);

    return 0;
}
```